# Django Rest Framework - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Getting "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'" error with Django 3.2.4 and djangorestframework 3.12.4

Logs:

```
backend     | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend     |   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
backend     |     main()
backend     |   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
backend     |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
backend     |     utility.execute()
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
backend     |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
backend     |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
backend     |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
backend     |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
backend     |     self.check(databases=[database])
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
backend     |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
backend     |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
backend     |     return check_resolver(resolver)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
backend     |     return check_method()
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
backend     |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
backend     |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
backend     |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
backend     |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
backend     |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
backend     |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
backend     |   File "/app/backend/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
backend     |     path('api/properties/', include('apps.properties.urls')),
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
backend     |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
backend     |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
backend     |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
backend     |   File "/app/apps/properties/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
backend     |     urlpatterns = router.urls
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 77, in urls
backend     |     self._urls = self.get_urls()
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 236, in get_urls
backend     |     routes = self.get_routes(viewset)
backend     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 152, in get_routes
backend     |     extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
backend     | AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Property
from .serializers import PropertySerializer

def PropertiesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer
```

**urls.py**

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import PropertiesViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()

router.register('properties', PropertiesViewSet, basename='properties')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Property

class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Property
       fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models


class Property(models.Model):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )

    property_address = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    host_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=False,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )

    current_certificate_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=False,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )

    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField()

    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    description = models.TextField(max_length=256)

    amenities = models.JSONField()

    total_bedrooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    longitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=7
    )

    latitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=9,
        decimal_places=7
    )

    max_guests = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.property_address

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "property"
        verbose_name_plural = "properties"
```

I've searched over all other questions, most of them are using APIViews as ViewSets, but it's not the case here. I've also tried adding the get_extra_actions functions (returning []), but it does not detect it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo:

```py
def PropertiesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer


# Should be class

class PropertiesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertySerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `urls.py` try setting the `urlpatterns` like

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import PropertiesViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register('properties', PropertiesViewSet, basename='properties')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

from [The Tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)

Comment: Odd that you'd need to do this - his example is directly from the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage